# backrefstyle=two not working with bibstyle=phys and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

I have a problem with back referencing, first a minimal example that I use:

```
\documentclass[headings=chapterprefix,12pt,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{german}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%für lustige Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false,labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\,\alph{subfigure})}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage[total={16.5cm,23cm}, inner=2cm, outer=3cm, footskip=1cm, headsep=0.75cm, twoside, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=black,
            urlcolor=black,
            citecolor=black
            ]{hyperref}
            \hypersetup{linktocpage}  

\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
    natbib=true,
    style=phys,
    biblabel=brackets,
    giveninits=true,
    abbreviate=false,
    doi=false, url=false, isbn=false,
    block=space,
    backref=true,
    backrefstyle=two,
    sorting=none
]{biblatex}
        

\addbibresource{lit.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1}%Journalname nicht kursiv
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
backrefpage={zitiert auf S\adddot},
backrefpages={zitiert auf den S\adddot}
}
```

In my document I use `\cite{Purdie2018}` on pages 1, 2 and 3.

At last I use:

```
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
    \printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
```

This gives me in my bibliography:

> [1] D. G. Purdie, N. M. Pugno, T. Taniguchi, K. Watanabe, A. C. Ferrari und A. Lombardo, Cleaning interfaces in layered materials heterostructures, Nature Communications 9, 5387 (2018) (zitiert auf den S. 1–3).

I would like to have "zitiert auf den S. 1,2 und 3" instead of this version. I thought `backrefstyle=two` should work with this but it doesn't.

Comment: Please translate your question into English.

Comment: Sorry i updated it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (p. 53 "`backrefstyle`")

> [`backrefstyle=two,`] Compress[es] any sequence of two or more consecutive pages to a range, e.g., the [list ‘1, 2, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 24’] is compressed to ‘1–2, 11–13, 21–24’.

Assuming the work was cited on pages 1, 2 and 3, `backrefstyle=two,` therefore compresses the pages to "1-3" as advertised.

There is also `backrefstyle=three,` which only compresses ranges of three or more, but even that does not help you here. The only option that comes close to you what you want in this instance is `backrefstyle=none,`.

If the only thing you need in addition is an "and" before the last page, you may want to try switching the list format for `pageref` from `list:plain` to `list:delim`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, backref=true, backrefstyle=none,]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DeclareListFormat{pageref}{%
  \ifnumless{\abx@pagerefstyle}{0}
    {\usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
     \ifhyperref
       {\hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}}
       {#1}}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{pageref:init}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{pageref:comp}{#1}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
       {\usebibmacro{pageref:dump}}
       {}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P (cit. on pp. 1, 2 and 3).]

Comment: Thanks a lot moewe that makes it a lot better, any chance to get "1, 2 und 3" , since backrefstyle=none is giving me "1, 2, 3"?

Comment: @Jogalf Not out of the box, no.

Comment: Well then i guess i stick with that solution. Thank you :)

Comment: @Jogalf Scrap that. I checked the definition for `backrefstyle=none,` and think I found something that could help. I'll edit the answer shortly.

Comment: It works perfectly, couldnt have wished for more, thank you very much !